# Phonegap/Cordova Material Design MDC

Tags: cordova, material-design, phonegap, material-components-web

I tried this example, MDC for Web, but did't work for some reason. https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting_started

I'm looking for tutorials for beginners on Material io (MDC) with phonegap/cordova.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-112-web/#1 ?

Comment: Thank you Tushar Tyagi, Just want I nedded